# How make make curves in a face's corner?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model this camera for a game. [image]

I am not modelling the same exact same features, but I want to make those types of curves. I have no idea how to make these given the model I am working with:

[image]

Is there a simple way to make those kind of curves? My only option by now is using the knife, but is not going to be symetric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could begin with these bevels:

[image]

Mirror, create these edge loops:

[image]

Bevel this vertex:

[image]

Clean the topology:

[image]

Inset with the B option (boundary):

[image]

Extrude inwards:

[image]

A bit of rework:

[image]